# arbitrage free price in martingale measures

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Consider a one-period market with $S^1_t,\cdots,S^n_t$, with $t=0,1$ the price process of $n$ assets, where $S_1$ is a risk-free asset: $S^1_0=1$,$S^1_1=1+R$. Assumes that this market satisfies the No-Arbitrage hypothesis and let $M$ denote the set of equivalent martingale measure. Note that each $\mathbb{Q} \in M$ can be viewed as a function that assigns a non-negative value $\mathbb{Q}[A]$ to each $A \subset \Omega$.

**(a)** Show that if $\mathbb{Q}_0$,$\mathbb{Q}_1 \in M$, then for any $0 \leq t \leq 1$, the probability measure $\mathbb{Q}_t$ defined by $$\mathbb{Q}_t[A] = (1-t) \mathbb{Q}_0[A]+ t\mathbb{Q}_1[A]$$ is also in $M$.

**(b)** Let $C$ be a contingent claim and $\Pi(C)$ denote the set of all arbitrage-free prices of $C$. Prove that $\Pi(C)$  is a point or an interval.

I solved part (a) easily by the linearity of expectations but I can't solve part (b). I actually find it counter intuitive that the arbitrage-free price of a contingent claim can be an interval. Can someone please give a hint on part (b)? Please just a hint!

Comment: (b) doesn't contain any question... But the reason that the arbitrage free price can be an interval is that the market model can be "incomplete", i.e. that there exist contingent claims which are not replicable.

Comment: I need to prove that,I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints to (b):

In an incomplete market $\Pi(C)$ is an interval because we put lower and upper bounds on the arbitrage free prices. For example the upper bound on the price of a non-replicable $C$ is
$$
\inf(E_{\mathbb{Q}}[X/(1+R)]:X\geq C, \: X \text{ is replicable})
$$
because if it would trade at a higher price than this, you could do arbitrage by selling $C$ and buying the portfolio replicating $X$.

Comment: then in a complete market its always a single point right?  I understand your reasoning but I still dont see why the upper bound and the lower bound arent equal even in the incomplete market? @user126540

Comment: @Albanian_EAGLE Yes. In an incomplete market its a single point because all claims are replicable, so both the upper and lower limit will be equal to $E_Q[C/(1+R)]$. In an incomplete market $C$ might not replicable, so the upper bound will be the price of the cheapest replicable claim bigger than $C$, while the lower bound will be the most costly replicable claim which is under $C$.